# Generic ActionResult return type for API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following use case for the `GetProducts()` method.

Good path: Returns array of type product: `Product[]`

Bad path: Returns status code of 500 and descriptive string error message.

(`<?Type?>` below is my own markup for the purposes of this post)

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<?Type?> GetProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            Product[] products = DataAccess.GetProductsFromDb();
            return products;
        }
        catch 
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return "Error retrieving products list"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can declare an action result of a generic type or perhaps two types so that this can work?

Comment: Use `Product[]` and throw an exception when "bad path" occurs. The built-in error handler will return status 500 with the message (you can further customize it by registering your own error handler)

Comment: I've read that throwing exceptions is a more expensive process which is why I avoided this method. Also I want to avoid potentially revealing the stack trace or any server details. Is this approach secure enough?

Comment: That's not how Web API works. Either return [OK(products)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or [NotFound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_NotFound)  if no products are found.

Comment: If you get an exception, the correct response is **500** - a server error. You can return that with [StatusCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: @Reed you already got an exception. Just *don't* catch it and ASP.NET Core will translate it to a 500 response. Directly accessing the `Response` object is a bad idea and makes testing your code a *lot* harder

Comment: @Reed all of this is explained in the documentation [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: public IActionResult GetProducts()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would return an IActionResult. I highly recommend making is async as well.
Here's how you can return anything through a controller method:

```
[Route("api/{controller}")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = await DataAccess.GetProductsFromDb();
        if (products is null)
        {
            return NotFound("Item not found!");
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(products);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `Ok` and `NotFound` are methods in the `Controller` abstract class which allows you to return any object you want, or no object at all.

I highly recommend before continuing using .net core you take a quick look at the example project template in Visual Studio, or if you're developing in another IDE run `dotnet new mvc` in your terminal.

If you want to handle an exception you should handle it on the lowest level. Assuming GetProductsFromDb() is the lowest level and you have no service layer (you'll regret this design choice later on!) you would put a try/catch.

```
[Route("api/{controller}")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts()
    {
        Products[] products;
        try
        {
            products = await DataAccess.GetProductsFromDb();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, "Unable to receive products");
            return InternalServerError("Unable to retrieve products, please try again later");
        }
        if (!products.Any())
        {
            return NotFound("No products were found");
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(products);
        }
    }
}
```

Speed is NOT more important than stability in most cases, and certainly not at this stage of development. the cost of catching an exception is insignificant on something so high-level, especially since your database call is going to be several orders of magnitude slower than the overhead of catching a single exception.

Comment: async method should await the DataAccess.GetProductsFromDb()

Answer (score 6):

You can return `ActionResult<Product[]>` as you wish.
For the error scenario, though, you can use the `StatusCode()` helper method to return your error message, as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Product[]> GetProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            Product[] products = DataAccess.GetProductsFromDb();
            return products;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Error retrieving products list");
        }
    }
}
```