# How to use ?? with return?

Tags: c#

I want to return `Todo` object whenever there is such an object, otherwise return `NotFound()`. I also want to use only a single line consisting of `return` and `??`. The following produces error at compile time. How to solve it?

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id) ?? NotFound();
}
```

## Attempt 1

[image]

## Attempt 2

[image]

## Attempt 3

MarTim's attempt passes the compiler,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return (IActionResult)(await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id)) ?? NotFound();
}
```

but generates runtime errors:

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615398/generic-actionresult-return-type-for-api-controller

Comment: It looks like the types don't match - `FindAsync` doesn't return an `ActionResult<Todo>`, it returns a `Todo`.

Comment: @CharlesMager: But `ActionResult` has a magic implicit cast operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's simplify it a bit:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    Todo todo = await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id);
    return todo ?? NotFound();
}
```

The problem here is that `todo` and `NotFound()` have very different types. `todo` is a `Todo`, but `NotFound()` returns a `NotFoundResult`. These two are inherently incompatible, and the compiler doesn't know that it should convert both of them to an `ActionResult<Todo>`.

If you want to keep the method's return type as `ActionResult<Todo>`, you can write:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return (await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id)) ?? new ActionResult<Todo>(NotFound());
}
```

Alteratively, you can use a helper method:

```
public static ActionResult<T> ResultOrNotFound<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    return item != null ? new ActionResult<T>(item) : new ActionResult<T>(NotFound());
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return ResultOrNotFound(await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id));
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're OK with returning an `IActionResult` instead, then you can do:

```
public static IActionResult OkOrNull(object item)
{
    return item != null ? Ok(item) : null;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public async Task<IActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return OkOrNull(await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id)) ?? NotFound();
}
```

You can make this look a bit nicer if you want, with another overload:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> OkOrNull<T>(Task<T> task) where T : class
{
    T item = await task;
    return item != null ? Ok(item) : null;
}
```

Meaning you can write:

```
public async Task<IActionResult<Todo>> GetTodo(long id)
{
    return await OkOrNull(_context.Todos.FindAsync(id)) ?? NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Oh no. You changed the requirement in which the solution must use only a single `return`.

Comment: It means there is no solution if I insist on using a single `return` and `??`?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I've added another option, which uses a helper method, but then means you can use `return` and `??`. I don't think you'll get closer than that unfortunately.

Comment: @canton7 you are missing a ')' in the last method before the '??'

Answer (score 2):

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTodo(long id) =>
    ToActionResult(await _context.Todos.FindAsync(id)) ?? NotFound();

private static IActionResult ToActionResult<T>(T x) 
    where T : class =>
        x == null
            ? null
            : ((IConvertToActionResult) new ActionResult<T>(x)).Convert();
```

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity You didn't copy this answer fully - this uses `Task<IActionResult>` as the return type

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I changed my answer and hope this works for you.

Comment: OK. But it does not conform to the requirements given in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I wasn't aware you really wanted to use the ?? operator. How about this?

Comment: @MarTim that won't work if `todo` is null? Since `(ActionResult<Todo>)null` is a perfectly valid `ActionResult<Todo>`, so you'll never get `NotFound()`

Comment: @canton7 you're right. I misread it and it does not return null. I will change my solution.

Comment: Cool, that's now the same as one of my solutions :)

Comment: Yes, pretty much!