# The null-coalescing operator doesn't accepts different types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I started out, returning a custom class:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult<Round> Get(string id) =>
    this._roundsService.Get(id);
```

The Get method in the rounds service can return null and that gets converted to HTTP 204 No Content. I was wondering how to return 404 when I get null:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult<Round> Get(string id) =>
    this._roundsService.Get(id) ?? NotFound();
```

Apperantly this doesn't work and gives me a CS0019 error: `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Round' and 'NotFoundResult'`

I'm open to other one-liners that would return the desired object if not null and 404 if null.

I'm using C# 8.0 with the netcoreapp3.0 framework. I haven't enabled the nullable feature. Could that be causing the problem?

Just in case, here's the method in the service class:

```cs
public Round Get(string id) =>
    this._rounds.Find(round => round.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: By the way, the `Round` class is also a class, therefore reference type and therefore nullable

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58412356/1086121

Comment: IIRC for a null-coalescing operator to accept two different types one side must be castable to the other. That is to say one side must either inherit the other or they must both be the same type. It's not enough for them to be two different types inheriting the same class, the null-coalescing operator doesn't consider what it's about to be cast to, only what it returns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `NotFound()`, you are creating a `NotFoundResult`. Your method has a return type of `ActionResult<Round>` but `NotFoundResult` doesn’t actually inherit from `ActionResult<Round>`, so you cannot return the `NotFoundResult` object directly.

When you do type `return NotFound()` then what actually happens is that the compiler will use the [implicit operator `ActionResult<T> (ActionResult)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1.op_implicit?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionResult_1_op_Implicit_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionResult__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionResult__0_) to transform the `NotFoundResult` into a `ActionResult<Round>`.

This works fine when you just return the value directly but it will not work when used within a ternary conditional or null-coalescing expression. Instead, you would have to do the conversion yourself:

```
public ActionResult<Round> Get(string id) =>
    this._roundsService.Get(id) ?? new ActionResult<Round>(NotFound());
```

Because the [constructor of `ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) accepts any `ActionResult`, you can just pass the `NotFoundResult` to it to make sure that it gets converted properly.

Of course, you can also split this up again and have the compiler do the conversion for you:

```
public ActionResult<Round> Get(string id)
{
    var result = this._roundsService.Get(id);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked! I still didn't understand: given an expression `A ?? B` does `B` has to be castable to `A` or is this only necessary if we're not returning directly like `public T Get() => A ?? B`

Comment: @MitkoRusev Of course it has to be casteable. var and short operators are **not** Dynamic. Compile time Type checks still happen fully. And especiall generics are there so we do not break compile time type checks.

Comment: @Christopher makes sense. But then why doesn't the compiler error when `A` is castable to `T`, `B` is castable to `T`, but `B` is not castable to `A`. Could that be a special feature of ??

Comment: @MitkoRusev That case is totally different. T is the return type. A can be cast into T. B can not. So `T variable = B value` is not a valid assignment. It does not mater in how few lines you sqeueezes it, it is still that set of seperate operations.

Comment: As long as `A` and `B` are both implicitly castable to the return type, I don't really get why you'd want it to error at compile time (`public T Get() => A ?? B` is then like `public T Get() => (T)A ?? (T)B`)

Comment: @Christopher no I get why we have to add the cast `(T) B`, because it isn't implicit, but still does there exist an exception to `B` must be castable to `A` when it's in a return expression

Comment: @Rafalon Look at Christopher's answer. We're discussing whether the operator expands to `result = NotFound()` or `return NotFound()` on the third line. More specifically does that only work when the operator is being used in a return expression

Comment: @MitkoRusev you're right, it looks more like `result = NotFound()` as it's indeed compile-erroring even if both `A` and `B` are castable to `T`. (`public T Get() => (T)A ?? B` would work though)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it cannot do that. It is only shorthand for a `if`. I think the equivalent to what you wrote would be around this:

```
ActionResult<Round> result = this._roundsService.Get(id);
if(result == null)
  result = NotFound();
return result;
```

And at this point, the compiler is really confused why you try to assign the "NotFound()" return value to a ActionResult variable.

Comment: I would expect it to be equivalent to: `if(temp == null) return NotFound(); else return temp;`. It could be that the compiler results into whta you gave as an example

Comment: @MitkoRusev While that might be closer to the actuall code, I would my example a bit clearer. Too much stuff in one line really only causes issues with understanding.

Comment: @Christopher Mitko only wrote it on one line because you can't format code in comments, but that would only mean replace `temp = NotFound();` with `return NotFound();` in your code